# Single translation for many locales

Tags: theme-development, translation, localization, l10n

Greetings to everyone,

Is it possible to do make a single translation for many locales? Let me explain it better: Can I create a single translation file for my theme called `es.po` and `es.mo` so it matches all possible variants for locales of the Spanish language? (i.e. `es_ES`, `es_MX`, etc.)

The idea here is to avoid copying the file several time to match all locales of the Spanish language.